# FATAL: role "root" does not exist, rails only on website, rails console works

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

So I inherited this mess of a rails project.

I am migrating the DB from mysql to postgres.

I am now encountering this error when trying to open my test webpage

ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError at /test
FATAL:  role "root" does not exist
Run `$ bin/rake db:create db:migrate` to create your database

This error occurs throughout the entire site.

BUT the rails console can connect to the DB and I can create objects in the DB via console.

this is my database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  host: localhost
  pool: 5

development:
  <<: *default
  database: aas_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: aas_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: aas_production
  username: aas
  password: <%= ENV['ASS_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create database user(Role):**

Postgres uses the concept of roles to distinguish the variety of users that can connect to a database. When it is first installed on a server, the default postgres user is actual named “postgres”.

**To create custom user, first switch into the default user:**

`sudo su – postgres`

**Now create new role(user) in PostgreSQL system :**

`createuser`

**It will propmpt you as follow :**

`Enter name of role to add: newuser`

`Shall the new role be a superuser? (y/n) y`

**If you want to set password for newly created Role(User) then command should be:**

`createuser --pwprompt`

**and Your database.yml should be like this.**

```
default: &default
 adapter: postgresql
 pool: 5
 timeout: 5000
 username: your_username
 password: your_password

development:
 <<: *default
 database: db_name_development

test:
 <<: *default
 database: db_name_test

production:
 <<: *default
 database: db_name
```

Comment: The role "root" does not exist anywhere in my database.yml, why would I need to create the user?
Besides my rails console command works and I can access the DB from there.
That means there is somewhere else is trying to access the DB using the "root" role?
No?